# Vectorized array operation, with excluding array elements by turns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am looking for the most efficient method in Python for a certain kind of vector operation, say,

- Obtain a array composed of the weighted sums of the products with all the other array elements, for each array element.

for example, suppose we have two arrays of same shape

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [ 1, 0, -1, 2]
```

What I would like to do is to construct a new array c with the same shape, such that

```
c[i] = ( sum of a[j]*b[j] while j!=i )
```

Threfore yields

```
c = [ 5, 6, 9, -2]
```

---

It is not that tough problem if we use multiple `for` loops, but it might be slow for very large arrays. I've heard using masked array `np.ma` gives some help, but it seems that the method still requires iterative masking of each elements.

I wonder if there is any other method faster than these, especially utilizing vectorized forms of opertations.

Comment: How do you get 3, the first element of c ?

Comment: Following your formula, I obtain c = [7, 6, 11, 0].

Comment: For me it's [ 5,  6,  9, -2] or [ 1,  1, -2,  6]

Comment: Oops seems I made a silly mistake. modified the list. Apologies. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NumPy`, of course:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [5]: b = np.array([1, 0, -1, 2])

In [6]: c = a * b

In [7]: c = c.sum() - c

In [8]: c
Out[8]: array([ 5,  6,  9, -2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to do it in plain numpy (bet there is). But as long as you are dealing with iterations, your way to go is the sum-iterator and list comprehension.

```
nsize = 500
a = np.random.randint(-3, 8, nsize)
b = np.random.randint(-3, 8, nsize)
```

A first idea to come up with would be plain for-loops. Solution would look like this:

```
c = list()
for i in range(nsize):
    sum_entry = 0
    for j in range(nsize):
        if not j == i:
            sum_entry += a[j] * b[j]
    c.append(sum_entry)
```

For nsize = 500, this took 0.098sec.

A faster and more pythonic way is combining the sum-iterator and list comprehension:

```
c = [sum(a[j]*b[j] for j in range(nsize) if not j == i) for i in range(nsize)]
```

nsize = 500 took me 0.075sec, so 30 % faster.

Comment: Seems it does work well. I wonder if the code still internally includes the procedure of comparing index when it runs.

Comment: It does iterate through indices, but list comprehensions are basically faster than for-loops.